# Popped fragment animation

Tags: java, android

I am trying to animate fragment popped from a backstack, but any attempt is a failure. Also i tried to SetCustomAnimation(int i1,int i2,int i3,int i4), but anything i did, it doesn't animate, just appear.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    else  if    (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right,android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        for(Fragment s:getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()){
            if(s!=null&&!s.isDetached()){
                ft.remove(s);
            }
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        ft.commit();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: use `fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.your_enter_animation, R.anim.your_exit_animation);` android version 19+

Comment: I find a answer for myself question, setCustomAnimation(int i,int i2,int 3,int 4) must be bound to initial fragment, before calling(onBackPressed).